# How to know if youtube video is available for mobile applications using youtube-v3-api

Tags: angular, youtube-api, ionic3, youtube-data-api

I am creating a multi-platform mobile application using ionic/cordova + angular native tools, and have trouble playing embedded videos from YT inside my application. Message I get is: "Video is unavailable".

I use youtube-v3-api for getting the video's info.

When I use this request https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=AQ0IsWLhgSg&part=status,contentDetails,player,recordingDetails&key=MY_KEY`, I get response:

```
{  
   "kind":"youtube#videoListResponse",
   "etag":"\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/k5WZx2_B4W8ER6xZbSQP_bYl4dk\"",
   "pageInfo":{  
      "totalResults":1,
      "resultsPerPage":1
   },
   "items":[  
      {  
         "kind":"youtube#video",
         "etag":"\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/2mhCEDnY5JrztmP_hTBHBci7iqY\"",
         "id":"AQ0IsWLhgSg",
         "contentDetails":{  
            "duration":"PT5M37S",
            "dimension":"2d",
            "definition":"hd",
            "caption":"false",
            "licensedContent":false,
            "projection":"rectangular"
         },
         "status":{  
            "uploadStatus":"processed",
            "privacyStatus":"public",
            "license":"youtube",
            "embeddable":true,
            "publicStatsViewable":true
         },
         "player":{  
            "embedHtml":"\u003ciframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/AQ0IsWLhgSg\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c/iframe\u003e"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Even the parameter **embedded** is set to **true**, this video can not be played inside my mobile application (ionic/cordova - tested on android phones).

What information here tells me that the specific video does not have the permission to be played on mobile?

Can you please also help me how to know, based on this response, if YT video can or can not be embedded inside ionic+cordova native mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache Cordova uses web technology (JS/HTML/CSS) for mobile, I suggest trying the [Youtube iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds) route instead.

You may also try this [SO post](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds) for additional reference.